# Detaching on Object / Entity OR DTO

Tags: java, hibernate, transactions, save, entities

I am getting this error `java.sql.BatchUpdateException: ORA-01732: data manipulation not legal on this view`. After investigation by our Admin, I was told that code is trying to update Read-only object.

I was told to do either of these ones.

1. Use separate Transaction
2. Rewrite the entity to DTO and use the DTO.

I googled for it and verified Hibernate docs. But I did not clear idea.  Can anyone point an example on this?

And another question, when query the DB and get entities, and then update it, like below:

```
 MyEntity.setName("Jon Doe");
```

and if I do not perform like `session.save` or something like that, does the entity get saved automatically or it should be somewhere in the code to commit these changes? (or it depends on, auto-commit option in Hibernate?).

Environment: Hibernate, JBoss 4.2.2, JPA and EJB. (No Spring)

Comment: That's the principle of JPA/Hibernate: you get an attached entity from the database, modify it, and the changes are automatically persisted.

Comment: So, I dont need to call `Save`, `update`, `saveOrUpdate`, `persist`, etc any of the methods like these?

Comment: save and persist are used to make a transient entity attached. SO they're necessary to insert a new row in a table. `update` and `saveOrUpdate` both take detached entities and make them attached. But if you already have an attached entity and modify it, you don't need to call any Session/EntityManager method to have the changes persisted in database.

Comment: Thats pretty clear. Thank you!